# I would like others to explain what is better load by file or leave on memory

Tags: android

I need to show medium text on my android program.

I have 20 types of text.

what is the best way for this:

1. Load to different vals the text
2. Load from files ?

if the best way is to load from files (2), can I get a sample ?

Comment: are the texts in the strings.xml file? and if not, why not?

Comment: no, the text not in string.xml

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that maybe is usefull

```
public void Data_read(View v) {

        Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Read2);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done reading SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            File myFile = new File(root + "yourfile.txt");
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    fIn));
            String aDataRow = "";
            String aBuffer = "";

            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
                Date lastModDate = new Date(myFile.lastModified());
                System.out.println("File last modified @ : "
                        + lastModDate.toString());
            }
            tv.setText(aBuffer);
            myReader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

You take a txt file, then read all rows and put them into and Textview.
This is just a sample code, so you maybe have to change it a little bit, so it fits in your own code

If you got any questions about this, you can always ask.

Comment: so it will be better to load from file ?

Comment: Sorry, had a day off yesterday.
I think it is better to load from a file, because you got more controll over it.